# Understanding AWS EB components

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ebs

I have a nodejs project repo containing multiple services. One client API and one worker process. I use redis for communication and queuing. Both these services needs to be in auto scaling group.

How would I setup this architecture in EB? Should I run both this services in single EB using multiple environments or Should I fire multiple EBs? If I am to fire multiple EBs for diffrent services then where would redis service reside? Would it be a part of any EB or be an isolated service?

How would a single project with multiple applications could be setup using AWS EB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run two separate EB environments and use ElastiCache, Amazon's managed Redis service.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy to multiple EBs from a single repo?